# React native WebView doesn't render anything

Tags: react-native

It's been a couple of days im tring to render something with react-native WebView.
Everything (an HTML file, a website) i try to render doesn't work nor on web nor on my iPhone X.

I installed the WebView component using: npm install react-native-webview

This is my code:

```
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";
<View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "column" }}>
        <WebView
            source={{
                html: "<html><body style='color:red'>Hello<br/>This is a test</body></html>",
            }}
            style={{
                width: 200,
                height: 200,
                backgroundColor: "blue",
                marginTop: 20,
            }}
        />
    </View>
```

Comment: please share the logs also confirm have you run react-native link after installing react-native webview

Comment: Logs are empty and i didn't run react-native link, what is that?

Comment: It's used to link native dependencies

Answer (score 0):

How about remove the

```
flexDirection: "column"
```

or the wrapping `<View>`?

It might be taking the height away from the WebView.

Comment: Nothing changes, i have tried almost everything with styles. I think it is a problem with webview...

Comment: Have you done  

     `npx pod-install ios`  ?

Comment: When you install anything to do with iOS native (like webView, this time), you need to install package for iOS, which are called Pods.

Comment: Installation guide is here: https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Getting-Started.md

You don't have to do `react native link`, do `pod install` instead.

Comment: Do i also need that if im testing on web?

Comment: No, pods are only for iOS.  If you are on the Web, there is no need to use react-native-webview itself...

Comment: I get this message "CocoaPods is only supported on darwin machines" when i run `npx pod-install ios`

Comment: Are you using Expo? or Bare React Native?

The error message means that CocoaPods are only available for MacOS.  If you are on Windows,  you can't develop iOS app. If that's the case, you can use Expo, which has dependencies bundled inside, so you can develop iOS on Windows.